# TypeError: Cannot read property 'returnValue' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

describe('ProductListComponent', () => {
  let component: ProductListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductListComponent>;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;
  let productService: ProductService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ProductListComponent ],
      imports: [FormsModule],
      providers: [ProductService]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductListComponent);
    productService = TestBed.get(ProductService);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
  });



  fit('should test filter product list (done)', (done)=> {
    //component.searchText='fresh';
    let productSpy = spyOn(productService, 'filterProductList').withArgs('fresh').and.callThrough();


    productSpy.calls.mostRecent().returnValue.then(()=>{
      fixture.detectChanges();
      const value = debugElement.query(By.css('#product_0')).nativeElement.innerText;
      expect(value).toContain(component.searchText);
      done();
    });


  });

});
```

I am trying to write the test case to filter the product list and have written a product spy, but it is giving an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'returnValue' of undefined
```

for the following line:

```
productSpy.calls.mostRecent().returnValue.then
```

I tried to find the solution online, but could not find a suitable solution.

Following is the service I am trying test:
1. filterProductList - will take in a string and filter through the list of product names and get the list of products - one matching the given string parameter

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  productList = PRODUCT_LIST;

  constructor() { }
  public getProductList(){
    return of(this.productList);
  }

  public filterProductList(searchString: string): Promise<any>{
    let dataObs: Observable<any>;
    //dataObs = of(this.productList.filter( product => product.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) > -1));
    //setTimeout(()=> { dataObs = of(this.productList.filter( product => product.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) > -1))},1000);
    return of(this.productList.filter( product => product.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) > -1)).toPromise();
  }
}

export const PRODUCT_LIST = [{
  "title": "Brown eggs",
  "type": "dairy",
  "description": "Raw organic brown eggs in a basket",
  "filename": "0.jpg",
  "height": 600,
  "width": 400,
  "price": 28.1,
  "rating": 4
}];
```

Comment: Given that try to get the most recent call immediately after spying on it, what call do you expect there to have been?

Comment: Can you add more info... like the component for you trying to write the spec. With this we are not sure what exactly you are trying.

Comment: I have added more details, hope it helps

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I am not getting what you are saying, sample / example will help

Comment: I'm just describing the example *you've already posted*. On one line, you spy on a method. On the very next line, you try to access a call to the spy. What do you think will have invoked the spied method between those two lines? If you think the spy will see calls that happened prior to you spying on the method, that will *not* happen.

Comment: *"Following is the service I am trying test"* - that test reads like it's for a *component*, not a service. Rather than spy on the real service why not create a test double, as shown in https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-async-service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method which was being spied on was never getting called, I got it after few trial and errors

```
fit('should test filter product list (done)', (done) => {
component.searchText = 'fresh';
let productSpy = spyOn(productService, 'filterProductList').withArgs('fresh').and.callThrough();

 **component.filterProductList({});**

productSpy.calls.mostRecent().returnValue.then(() => {
     fixture.detectChanges();
     const value = debugElement.query(By.css('#product_0')).nativeElement.innerText;
     expect(value).toContain(component.searchText);
     done();
   });
 });
```